# Python regex match but not include characters beautiful soup

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am using beautiful soup and requests to put down information from a webpage, I am trying to get a list of book titles that are just the titles and do not include the text title= in font of the title.

Example text = 'a bunch of junk title=book1 more junk text title=book2'

what I am getting is titleList = ['title=book1', 'title=book2']

I want titleList = ['book1', 'book2']

I have tried matching groups and that does break the words title= and book1 apart but I am not sure how to append just group(2) to the list.

```
titleList = []

def getTitle(productUrl):

  res = requests.get(productUrl, headers=headers)
  res.raise_for_status()

  soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
  title = re.compile(r'title=[A-Za-z0-9]+')
  findTitle = title.findall(res.text.strip())
  titleList.append(findTitle)
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the html that you are working with?

Comment: Is this really a BeautifulSoup question? You don't actually use `soup` object.

Comment: the question is why you use beautifulsoup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex has no capture groups. You should also note that `findall` returns a list so you should use `extend` instead of `append` (unless you want `titleList` to be a list of lists).

```
title = re.compile(r'title=([A-Za-z0-9]+)')   # note parenthesis
findTitle = title.findall(res.text.strip())
titleList.extend(findTitle)   # using extend and not append
```

A stand-alone example:

```
import re

titleList = []
text = 'a bunch of junk title=book1 more junk text title=book2'

title = re.compile(r'title=([A-Za-z0-9]+)') 
findTitle = title.findall(text.strip())
titleList.extend(findTitle) 
print(titleList)
>> ['book1', 'book2']
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I all of my searching I did not find the extend option, also just adding the capture group, I just needed a second pair of eyes.

Answer (score 2):

Using `re.findall` with a capture group will do it:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = 'a bunch of junk title=book1 more junk text title=book2'
>>> re.findall(r'title=(\S+)', text)
['book1', 'book2']
>>>
```